# Find the shortest distance between $z^2 = xy$ and (1,2,4)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm in Multivariable/Vector calculus and this is the final question on the final review. Initially I thought to use a lagrange variable to solve this problem but that resulted in an algebraic nightmare. $$ \lambda = \frac{2y-4}{x} = \frac{2x-2}{y} $$
Am I just missing something in my algebra, is there another way to solve this without a lagrange multiplier, or do I just have to do the algebra? Thank you!

EDIT: To clarify, here's the way I did the Lagrange Multiplier.
$$ f(x,y,z) = d^2 = (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-4)^2 $$
$$ g(x,y,z) = 0 = xy-z^2 $$
$$ \nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$$
$$ \lambda y = 2x-2$$
$$ \lambda x = 2y-4$$

And then, from there, I solved for lambda which resulted in the "algebra nightmare". Sorry for not initially including that.

Comment: I just added that in my edit! Sorry about that!

Comment: @Daniel Apsley I think there is a mistake in the given because finely we get very ugly numbers.

Comment: @Micheal Rosenberg That's too bad. My professor always writes his reviews in notepad documents so they almost always have errors like that.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the $\frac\partial{\partial z}$ term; that will allow you to solve for $\lambda$ in terms of $z$, and then you should be able to combine that information with the equalities you posted at the top (and the original equation $z^2=xy$) to find the point in question.